# Wordpress post custom order not working (showing up but not saving)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently doing my own wordpress theme and therefore need a custom post order. However, I am able to activate the post attribute's order within the wordpress gutenberg editor with the following code

```
add_post_type_support('post','page-attributes');
```

but it does not save when saving the post and always resets back to 0.

I already tried disabling all plugins and also checked the error with another wordpress theme (and the code shown) and another plain wordpress blog but it seems to not save my order set.

I also checked the post within the database and there is "menu_order" set to 0. When changing this manually to 5 or some other number, I can use this parameter for my custom order but gutenberg editor still shows up 0 as post attributes order.

Any ideas what I did wrong or is this a wordpress bug. Any chances to fix this? The order attribute of pages seems to work within gutenberg editor.

Answer (score 2):

With Gutenberg, WordPress is using the REST API to handle data. Because of that, you need to work with two filters to allow you to save that field, and then display the result in the admin. Those two filters are: `rest_pre_insert_post` and `rest_prepare_post`.

This is because WordPress has the schemas for the default posts hard-coded, which you can see in `/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php` @ line 1997. The schema for the default post doesn't include `page-attributes`. This is the workaround that I came up with for a project that I was working on: https://gist.github.com/jesgs/e619bfbfe10ad998d8a61ac41cc958a7